# Change a JComponent's attribute

Tags: java, swing, components, paintcomponent

I have a simple JPanel so far, and some basic elements like a string to display, a rectangle and a JButton, all on this panel. When I click with the mouse on this panel, I want the things that use the custom color 'rainbowColor' change their color to exactly that color ( the string and the rectangle ).

```
int red = 0;
int green = 255;
int blue = 0;
Color rainbowColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
boolean whichColor = true;

if (whichColor) { red = 255; blue = 0; whichColor = false; }
else { red = 0; blue = 255; whichColor = true; }
```

My 'TEXT' appears to be green all the time, no matter if I click my panel. At least this means the code works in some way. I still don't understand: the code says that 'whichColor' is set to true, so it should set 'red' to 255. Only the 'paintComponent { ... }' part is important ( my guess ) in this case. I really don't know what have I done wrong, thank you very much for helping me!

```
package game;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class Menu extends JPanel {

       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                int margin = 4;
                int red = 0;
                int green = 255;
                int blue = 0;
                Color rainbowColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
                boolean whichColor = true;

                if (whichColor) { red = 255; blue = 0; whichColor = false; }
                else { red = 0; blue = 255; whichColor = true; }

          super.paintComponent(g);
          Font customFont = new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 20);
          g.setFont(customFont);
          g.setColor( new Color(0,0,0));
          g.drawString( "TEXT", 20, 30 );
//        randomiseColor(randomColor);
          g.setColor(rainbowColor);
          g.drawString( "TEXT", 22, 32 );
          g.drawRect(margin, margin, getWidth() - margin*2 - 1, getHeight() - margin*2 - 1);
       }

    }

public static class RandomColorOnClick implements MouseListener {

       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
          Component source = (Component)evt.getSource();
          source.repaint(); 
       }

       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) { }
       public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) { }
       public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) { }
       public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) { }

    }

public static void main(String[] args){

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    double width = screenSize.getWidth();
    double height = screenSize.getHeight();

    RandomColorOnClick colorListener = new RandomColorOnClick();    
    ButtonHandler listener = new ButtonHandler();

    Menu main_text = new Menu();
    JPanel main_content = new JPanel();
    JFrame main_window = new JFrame("Some random text");
    JButton main_exit_button = new JButton("Exit");

    main_content.addMouseListener(colorListener);

    main_window.setContentPane(main_content);
    main_window.setSize(800, 600);
    main_window.setLocation(((int)width / 2) - 400, ((int)height / 2) - 300);
    main_window.setVisible(true);
    main_window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    main_content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    main_content.add(main_text, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    main_exit_button.addActionListener(listener);




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 problems

1) you have create `boolean whichColor=true;` inside the `paintComponent()` method(); so every time it draw the graphics, it creates a `whichcolor` variable and it's always true.create it outside of `paintcomponent` method as a instance variable .

2) creating color variable before change the colors.you are creating color variable but you change color after that.so color variable remain unchanged.
 `Color rainbowColor = new Color(red, green, blue);`
.that's why it's always green. you and move color creating line after the if-else condition .but you can declare it outside and change color instead of creating again and again.

here is an example ...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu extends JPanel {

    private boolean whichColor = true;
    private Color rainbowColor;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        int margin = 4;
        int red = 0;
        int green = 255;
        int blue = 0;

        if (whichColor) {
            red = 255;
            blue = 0;
            whichColor = false;
        } else {
            red = 0;
            blue = 255;
            whichColor = true;
        }
        rainbowColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Font customFont = new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 20);
        g.setFont(customFont);
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        g.drawString("TEXT", 20, 30);
//        randomiseColor(randomColor);
        g.setColor(rainbowColor);
        System.out.println(rainbowColor);
        g.drawString("TEXT", 22, 32);
        g.drawRect(margin, margin, getWidth() - margin * 2 - 1, getHeight() - margin * 2 - 1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        double width = screenSize.getWidth();
        double height = screenSize.getHeight();

        RandomColorOnClick colorListener = new RandomColorOnClick();
        ButtonHandler listener = new ButtonHandler();

        Menu main_text = new Menu();
        JPanel main_content = new JPanel();
        JFrame main_window = new JFrame("Some random text");
        JButton main_exit_button = new JButton("Exit");

        main_content.addMouseListener(colorListener);

        main_window.setContentPane(main_content);
        main_window.setSize(800, 600);
        main_window.setLocation(((int) width / 2) - 400, ((int) height / 2) - 300);
        main_window.setVisible(true);
        main_window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        main_content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        main_content.add(main_text, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        main_exit_button.addActionListener(listener);
    }

}

class RandomColorOnClick implements MouseListener {

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
        Component source = (Component) evt.getSource();
        source.repaint();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thank you very much Fast Snail, with your help I could understand it

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized colour object after changing values of red, blue, green variables.
Get color object initialized again if you are changing values of red blue green variables...